# Database returns an Empty value in mySql server

Tags: php, sql, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API for making routes. When I define a route, the value goes into the database but returns an empty value. The primary key in the database is incremented but other values are empty. Any idea?

```
<?php
session_start();

// connection to mysql
$latitude=$_POST['Lat'];
$longitude=$_POST['Long'];
$start_point=$_POST['s_point'];
$end_point=$_POST['e_point'];

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456","db_mmw") or die ("Error" .mysqli_errno($link));

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_route (latitude,longitude,start_point,end_point)  VALUES ('".$latitude."','".$longitude."','".$start_point."','".$end_point."')";

if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql))
  {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
mysqli_close($link); ?>
```

Comment: Post it in your question, not here.

Comment: how to show my html file i am new plz guide me

Comment: Never mind, I see what the error is (*from your now deleted comment containing the HTML form*). Consult my answer below. @user3542393

Comment: Do I need to mention "watch out for SQL injection"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted in your (*now deleted*) comment is that your form contains `name="long"` and  `name="lat"`

Those don't match your:

```
 $latitude=$_POST['Lat']; // uppercase L
 $longitude=$_POST['Long']; // uppercase L
 $start_point=$_POST['s_point'];
 $end_point=$_POST['e_point'];
```

Change it to:

```
 $latitude=$_POST['lat']; // lowercase l
 $longitude=$_POST['long']; // lowercase l
 $start_point=$_POST['s_point'];
 $end_point=$_POST['e_point'];
```

- **PHP variables are case-sensitive**

---

***Sidenote:*** Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo)

**Edit/Rewrite:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456","db_mmw") or die ("Error" .mysqli_errno($link));

// connection to mysql
$latitude=$_POST['lat'];
$longitude=$_POST['long'];
$start_point=$_POST['s_point'];
$end_point=$_POST['e_point'];



// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_route (latitude,longitude,start_point,end_point)  VALUES ('".$latitude."','".$longitude."','".$start_point."','".$end_point."')";

if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql))
    { 
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

---

### This is another issue:

```
<input type="submit" name="Define Route" value="Define Route"
```

is outside your form which will prevent it from working, plus there was a missing `>` and should have read as:

```
<input type="submit" name="Define_Route" value="Define Route">
```

I  changed it `name="Define Route"` to `name="Define_Route"` just in case.

```
<div class ="form"> 
<form method="post" action=""><br> <table border="0"> 
<tr> <td>Start Point</td><td> 
<input type="text" name="s_point"></td> </tr> <tr> 
<td>End Point</td><td> <input type="text" name="e_point"></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> Latitude </td><td> <input type="text" name="lat"></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> Longitude </td><td> <input type="text" name="long"></td> </tr> </table> 

<input type="submit" name="Define_Route" value="Define Route">

</form> 
<br><br> </div> 
</div>
```

---

### Complete rewrite with form that worked for me.

Using `VARCHAR(255)` for all four columns.

(Use in one file)

```
<?php
session_start();

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456","db_mmw") or die ("Error" .mysqli_errno($link));

if(isset($_POST['Define_Route'])){
// connection to mysql
$latitude=$_POST['lat'];
$longitude=$_POST['long'];
$start_point=$_POST['s_point'];
$end_point=$_POST['e_point'];


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_route (latitude,longitude,start_point,end_point)  VALUES ('".$latitude."','".$longitude."','".$start_point."','".$end_point."')";

if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql))
    { 
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['Define_Route']))

mysqli_close($link);

?>

<div class ="form"> 
<form method="post" action=""><br> <table border="0"> 
<tr> <td>Start Point</td><td> 
<input type="text" name="s_point"></td> </tr> <tr> 
<td>End Point</td><td> <input type="text" name="e_point"></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> Latitude </td><td> <input type="text" name="lat"></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> Longitude </td><td> <input type="text" name="long"></td> </tr> </table> 

<input type="submit" name="Define_Route" value="Define Route">

</form> 
<br><br> </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure that all columns exist with proper column types and have no typos in it. You should post your form and DB schema in your question. @user3542393 This should work.

Comment: now its giving following errors.
 Undefined index: lat in C:\wamp\www\fyp\actions\new_route.php on line 5
 Undefined index: long in C:\wamp\www\fyp\actions\new_route.php on line 6
 Undefined index: s_point in C:\wamp\www\fyp\actions\new_route.php on line 7
 Undefined index: e_point in C:\wamp\www\fyp\actions\new_route.php on line 8

Comment: Show me the actual HTML form. @user3542393 Even if you have to post it here in a comment, I'll take care of it if you can't post it in your question.

Comment: <div class ="form">
 <form method="post" action="new_route.php"><br>
 <table border="0">
<tr>
<td>Start Point</td><td> <input type="text" name="s_point"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>End Point</td><td> <input type="text" name="e_point"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Latitude </td><td> <input type="text" name="lat"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Longitude </td><td> <input type="text" name="long"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form> <br><br>
</div>

 <input type="submit" name="Define Route" value="Define Route" 
</div>

Comment: i also echo the querry but the result of querry is:
INSERT INTO tbl_route (latitude,longitude,start_point,end_point) VALUES ('','','','')

Comment: Theoretically, you shouldn't have a space inside `name="Define Route"` try with an underscore `name="Define_Route"` however I doubt that would make a difference. Reload my answer and look under "**Edit/Rewrite**" to make sure you did in fact copy it correctly. @user3542393 What are your column types for `latitude` and `longitude` and do they both in fact exist?

Comment: Wait, reload my answer again under "Edit/Rewrite". I placed your `$link...` DB connection first. Try it now. @user3542393

Comment: plz give me ur skype id or gmail id i can send u my database and html too

Comment: Something else I noticed, `<input type="submit" name="Define Route" value="Define Route" ` is outside your form. Place it above `</form>` and change it to `<input type="submit" name="Define Route" value="Define Route">` there was a `>` missing @user3542393

Comment: See under "**Complete rewrite with form that worked for me.**" (in my edit) that worked for me. @user3542393 I don't have Skype, sorry.

Comment: Great news, glad to hear it. You're welcome. @user3542393 Click on the **white gray outline checkmark/tick** next to my answer till it turns **Green** to accept as answered. cheers (It's right under the little up and down arrows over to the left of my answer).